# Is it possible to add channel-specific data to a HeroCard's CardAction?

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing with BotFramework, specifically targeting the Facebook Messenger channel.

CardActions, say on a HeroCard, translate into buttons in Messenger.

If a CardAction's Type is 'OpenUrl', Messenger will try to open a webview in the app with the supplied URL.

Messenger uses an optional 'Messenger Extensions' to turbocharge the webview experience, whereby if you call the webview in the right way and whitelist your domain in your FB settings, you allow the webview a few more permissions, such as the ability for it to close itself with Javascript, for example.

This requires setting the 'messenger_extensions' property to 'true' in the native properties of the JSON button, if you're just setting the ChannelData with Facebook-specific JSON.

But if you're doing it the generic BotFramework way, say

```
            new HeroCard("Title here", "and more", 
                buttons: { new CardAction()
            {
                Title = "Open in webview",
                Type = ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                Value = "https://example.com/webviews/1"
            } });
```

Is it possible to set messenger_extensions:true for this CardAction? Or is it only possible by doing the entire hero card in a Messenger-channel-specific list/button template in JSON in the message's ChannelData?

Comment: This would have to be accomplished in Channel data at this point.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Suspected as much :(

Comment: Do you have a working example of this as I'm in the same situation and I cannot find any documentation at all. Thanks

Comment: Look up the Messenger API's documentation, e.g. for list templates, and you'll see the JSON expected in the ChannelData. Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/oflahero/791403b197d8eeb97458cd8cc679ba44