# What is the purpose of CardAction.ChannelData?

Tags: c#, botframework, slack, azure-bot-service

I'm using the .NET BotFramework v4 with Azure Bot Service and am rendering a `HeroCard` with a set of buttons in a message like so:

```cs
var card = new HeroCard
{
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
    {
        new()
        {
            Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
            Value = "42",
            Title = "The answer"
        },
        new()
        {
            Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
            Value = "0",
            Title = "Wrong answer"
        }
    }
};
var message = MessageFactory.Text(message.Message);
message.Attachments.Add(heroCard.ToAttachment());
```

I noticed that `CardAction` has a `ChannelData` property. I hoped to use that to customize the style of a button for Slack users.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446637/is-it-possible-to-add-channel-specific-data-to-a-herocards-cardaction) suggests that not possible. If I want to style a single button, it sounds like I have to dump this approach and just override the entire `ChannelData` for `IMessageActivity`.

Is that still the case? And if so, how does Azure Bot Service make use of `CardAction.ChannelData`? What is it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried every card action property in every channel. As far as I can tell, the channel data property is never used.

This might make sense to you when we consider the nature of the Bot Framework schema. The original idea behind the Bot Framework was to have a way to build one bot that works on many different channels. This works very well when it comes to ordinary text messages, but different channels have wildly different ideas of how they handle things like attachments and interactive messages. The Bot Framework team came up with something called "cards" to generalize the UI objects found in different channels, like Facebook Messenger's "templates" and Telegram's "inline keyboards." In order to do this, the team had to account for a lot of different abilities and possibilities found in all the channels. Since it was hard to predict what abilities a card action might need when the schema was designed ahead of time, it's understandable why the developers wanted to err on the side of caution and give a card action extra properties even though they weren't sure to be used.

So it's very likely that a card action's channel data is just a relic of the Bot Framework schema's original spec.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that context. I suspect you're correct. It'd be nice to get a definite answer from the developers that this is a holdover relic. Might be nice to put the `ObsoleteAttribute` on it. :smile:

Comment: Whoops, I meant to continue. I think you're the same one who helped me with this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/299#issuecomment-841559247. I think my confusion over the mental model about ChannelData there lead to my question here. And now it's cleared up in both places! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ChannelData` is the way to send channel-specific info from the bot to the channel, and ultimately to the provider (say Slack), that's not included in the Bot Framework schema.

However, the way that info is converted to what the channel requires is specific to the adapter implementation.

There is a [`SlackAdapter`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Adapters/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Adapters.Slack/SlackAdapter.cs) in Bot Framework SDK that has a the `SendActivitiesAsync()` method, (as any other adapter) that currently uses the [`SlackHelper.ActivityToSlack`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/ececa515fc05c331d4ceeeca4b2b031fee39958c/libraries/Adapters/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Adapters.Slack/SlackHelper.cs#L36) method to create whatever Slack requires.

You could create your own `HaackedSlackAdapter` inheriting from `SlackAdapter` and override `SendActivitiesAsync()` to send exactly what you need.

Then you'd only have to send from the bot, in the `ChannelData` whatever you need to send to Slack, so your new adapter can "translate" it to Slack lingo.

So, to answer the other part of your answer, you'd have to create a complete new message to send to Slack or maybe just tweak the result from the `SlackHelper`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't apply to my situation. `SlackAdapter` is used when connecting directly to Slack. I'm connecting via `Azure Bot Service`. I understand in general what ChannelData is for. I don't understand how Azure Bot Services uses `ChannelData` on `CardAction`.

Comment: Oh, well, I'm sorry... I don't know that  Anyway I just found [this documentation that looks somewhat related](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-a-full-fidelity-slack-message), but I guess you might've already seen it.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that documentation. I understand that I can set the entire message's `ChannelData`. What I was hoping for though, was I wouldn't have to if I just want to customize one button. I was hoping I could just set the channel data on that `CardAction`. But it seems like `ChannelData` on `CardAction` is ignored. So I'm trying to understand what its purpose is.